# Libgdx - How to store evrey touch point on drag path?

Tags: java, libgdx

Whenever i try to store points on drag event ,if i drag a little faster it doesn't store each and every point i drag on screen.

What should i do that it stores each and every point on my touch path?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of Java, or LibGDX. There are two possible causes:

1. Your touchscreen digitizer has low refresh rate so that it just can't
   keep up with your finger's speed.
2. Your main loop has a performance issue and something inside loop
   takes such a long time that you can't get enough number of touch 
   events.

Either way, the result will be the same.